# Trying to test the queue persistence. Can't send messages when breakpoint on consumer

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I'm trying to test the queue persistence of ActiveMQ.

I have an embedded ActiveMQ server with an unique consumer.
This embedded server receive JMS messages from many other JVM applications.

It works fine, consumer application receive the notifications.

So i've tried to test the persistence of the messages.
I've put a (remote) breakpoint on the MessageListener of the consumer so that i can enqueue many messages and make the ActiveMQ server crash.
On server restart, i'd like all the enqueued messages to be able to be consumed, and not to be lost.

And then i tried that test.
I got into that breakpoint on the first message send.
But for all messages i try to send, i get the following stacktrack on the producer side:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occured during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: Wire format negotiation timeout: peer did not send his wire format.
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:316)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:168)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:469)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:534)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:612)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:604)
    at com.xxxxxxxxxxx.mobilepush.client.RealClientTest.main(RealClientTest.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Wire format negotiation timeout: peer did not send his wire format.
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:62)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1380)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.ensureConnectionInfoSent(ActiveMQConnection.java:1466)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.createSession(ActiveMQConnection.java:308)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createSession(JmsAccessor.java:196)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:457)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Wire format negotiation timeout: peer did not send his wire format.
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.oneway(WireFormatNegotiator.java:98)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.oneway(MutexTransport.java:68)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.asyncRequest(ResponseCorrelator.java:81)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.request(ResponseCorrelator.java:86)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1351)
    ... 13 more
```

I don't understand why my producer would be blocked when my consumer is in my breakpoint.

My broker uri is: `mobilepush.activemq.broker.transport.connector.uri=tcp://0.0.0.0:61616`

The producer connects through tcp to the broker.
The consumer, colocated with the broker, connects through `vm://localhost`.

---

My configuration is pretty simple:

```
SERVER:

    <!--  lets create an embedded ActiveMQ Broker -->
    <amq:broker useJmx="false" persistent="true">
        <amq:transportConnectors>
            <amq:transportConnector uri="${mobilepush.activemq.broker.transport.connector.uri}" />
        </amq:transportConnectors>
        <amq:persistenceAdapter>
            <amq:kahaPersistenceAdapter directory="${mobilepush.activemq.broker.queue.persistence.directory}" maxDataFileLength="100 Mb"/>
        </amq:persistenceAdapter>
    </amq:broker>
```

---

```
CONSUMER:
(management namespace and xebia class it only a JMX decorator)

<bean id="connectionFactory" class="fr.xebia.management.jms.SpringManagedConnectionFactory">
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" >
                <property name="brokerURL" value="${mobilepush.activemq.broker.uri}"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="pushConsumer" class="com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mobilepush.messaging.jms.PushConsumer">
        <property name="jmsPushMessageConverter" ref="jmsPushMessageConverter"/>
        <property name="pushDelegate" ref="directPushDelegate"/>
    </bean>

    <management:executor-service id="pushConsumerExecutor"
                                 pool-size="${mobilepush.consumer.thread.min}-${mobilepush.consumer.thread.max}" keep-alive="60" />

    <jms:listener-container
            task-executor="pushConsumerExecutor"
            connection-factory="connectionFactory"
            acknowledge="auto"
            container-class="fr.xebia.springframework.jms.ManagedDefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <jms:listener destination="mobilepush.queue" ref="pushConsumer" method="onMessage" />
    </jms:listener-container>
```

---

```
PRODUCER:

    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"  >
        <property name="brokerURL" value="${mobilepush.activemq.broker.uri}"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="mobilePushJmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="defaultDestination" ref="mobilePushQueue"/>
        <property name="messageConverter" ref="jmsPushMessageConverter"/>
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <!-- lets wrap in a pool to avoid creating a connection per send -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
                <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
                    <ref local="connectionFactory" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem!

The remote breakpoint i put on my embedded ActiveMQ consumer was a default breakpoint with suspend-policty=all.

And as the consumer and the server runs on the same JVM, i was also suspending all the ActiveMQ server threads!

The solution is to use a breakpoint suspend-policy=thread so that only the consumer thread is suspended and the server threads can continue to run.

Answer (score 0):

`"java.io.IOException: Wire format negotiation timeout: peer did not send his wire format"` seems pretty clear.  you are blocking the client thread which is the other end of the network connection.  the server is getting network timeouts trying to interact with the client.  network connections are a situation where it's hard to debug by arbitrarily suspending a thread.

Comment: Yes i understand, but while the consumer is busy, aren't we supposed to still be able to send messages??? The client thread is supposed to be executed on the thread pool i provided so why the hell it would block the sender???

Comment: @SebastienLorber - dunno, maybe the activemq server is single threaded.

Answer (score 0):

The activemq broker will wait for a few seconds for the client to send the wire format before forcing a disconnect. On your connection URL try adding the following parameter to extend that time to something that will allow you to do your debugging:

```
tcp://localhost:61616?wireFormat.maxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=30000
```

The integer value is the number of miliseconds to wait.

Comment: I know, read the ActiveMQ page about that. I tried and this only makes the exception be raised 20 seconds later than it used to be...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by using the latest logback-core and logback-classic jar file which is 1.1.2